# ImageMagick converts SVG to PNG with wrong fonts

Tags: php, image, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I get squares instead of the text I enter in SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="200px" height="200px" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<text font-size="40px" x="0" y="50" font-family="Arial" >
            123456789 ABCDEFGH
</text>

</svg>
```

Then I convet it to PNG on PHP with this code:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
$output = shell_exec("convert -size 280x280 test.svg png:- "); 
echo  $output; 
?>
```

and I get these squares instead of the text I entered:

[image]

Any ideas on how to control these fonts?

I've found a link that shows great control of fonts but I couldn't
understand exactly how they did it:
http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/server/fonts.php

Comment: I read Imagemagick isn't fully able to convert svg to something else. But there is a tool on github which is. https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport

Comment: Thanks @CharlotteDunois but I need it to funciton in PHP. I want the SVG hidden from the client browser. I would have usen CANVAS for that...

Comment: Well, you're already using `shell_exec()` to execute a command line, why not do the same with svgexport?

Comment: AFAIK, `-size` isn't a valid ImageMagick parameter. Your squares may be an error message.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Removed it, but I get the same squares. Thanks

Comment: Are you using an up-to-date version? Have you tried using `rsvg` instead of `svg` delegate?

Answer (score 1):

First, check which version of ImageMagick you are running and upgrade if it is old - the world moves fast with the Web these days!

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-09-04 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Secondly, consider using the `rsvg` delegate - you can list delegates like this:

```
identify -list delegate | grep svg
    cdr =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    cgm =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    dot =>          "dot" -Tsvg "%i" -o "%o"
    dxf =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    fig =>          "uniconvertor" "%i" "%o.svg"; mv "%o.svg" "%o"
    svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"
```

Thirdly, check which fonts you have installed, like this:

```
identify -list font

  Font: Arial
    family: Arial
    style: Undefined
    stretch: Undefined
    weight: 0
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf
  Font: ArialB
    family: Arial
    style: Undefined
    stretch: Undefined
    weight: 0
    glyphs: /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial Bold.ttf
```

Finally, if you run your command on my system you get this - I have added a black border so you can see the extents.

[image]